# Which is the better hiding place for a Kenyan Sand Boa?

Tags: snakes, substrate

Which would be more important, deeper substrate or a pair of caves (one on the hot side and one on the warm)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to want both ideally. The deep substrate is good for burrowing (which they will do) but not deep enough to cut down on the heat. I would say at least 1 hide and deeper substrate is probably fine but two hides are good for most terrestrial snakes. According to the [care sheet](http://www.reptilesmagazine.com/Care-Sheets/Snakes/Kenyan-Sand-Boa/) sand boas also destroy their environment so dont get a ton of stuff in there and also dont get heavy hides for when they burrow so it doesn't injure themselves

Comment: and to answer your question, At least 1 hide is more important than substrate because they snake will push up substrate to burrow no matter how much you have

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer accepted. I've since learned you are right and have two hides and deep substrate. Thanks, I had forgotten this one.